# How to include validate_email package into django UserCreationForm?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-registration

I downloaded an email validator package from PyPI ([link](https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/)), and by using

```
pip install validate email
```

and

```
pip install py3dns
```

(since my python is version 3.6.7) into my django project.

The problem is I cannot get the `validate_email` function to work on my django project, so that I am wondering what code should I be writing on my django's `forms.py` and `views.py` (not using `models.py` yet).

Please tell me what did I do wrong and what changes should be made to my current code in `forms.py`.

I included

`from django.core.validators import validate_email`

as seen in `forms.py` below, to try to validate the email entered by any user, but it seems that the `validate_email` works differently from the `validate_email` from `from validate_email import validate_email`.

The validation that I need is from PyPI as it is more accurate in validation (e.g. can check if an email is existent or not) whereas the `validate_email` form django.validators only checks for invalid format and thats it.

```
/* forms.py */
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from validate_email import validate_email


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

    def clean_email(self):
        email_passed = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        email_req = "yourdomain.com"
        if not email_req in email_passed:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid email format")
        return email

/* views.py */

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            # do something with phone number??
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

I expect the output to validate the email from the django form's email field by using get method to get the email and do validation using validate_email. 
for example, if the entered email is "ifewheieuiower34@gmail.com" which is a non-existent email, the form should raise an error stating that the email does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the `validate_email` function from the package in your clean method. You can call it in your `clean_email` method like this

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    if not validate_email(email):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid email")
    return email
```

Comment: A colon is missing in the if statement.